# Copying charts to powerpoint while keeping source formatting

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have a excel sheet containing a pie chart and i would like to copy it to a PowerPoint slide (slide number 10).

I would also want to **keep the source formatting** where by **if i make any format changes** in the pie chart **it should amend in the slide as well**.

Is there any vba coding for this? Came across this code but it does not seem to work for me.

```
'copy the chart from Excel
        xlSheet.ChartObjects(ChartName).Select
        xlSheet.ChartObjects(ChartName).Copy
    'Select Slide
        Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(Charts(r).SlideName)
        mySlide.Select
    'stall to make sure the slide is selected
        For k = 1 To 1000
            DoEvents
        Next k
    'paste on selected slide
        PPApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
        PPApp.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus
    'sit and wait for changes to be made
        For k = 1 To 5000
            DoEvents
        Next k
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally use the `PasteSpecial` method like this :

```
xlSheet.Charts(ChartName).ChartArea.Copy

Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(Charts(r).SlideName)

'Use paste special method
mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile, Link:=msoTrue

mySlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Chart Title"

'Free the Object variable
Set mySlide = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the CommandBars method from 2010 onwards although it implies having the PowerPoint window in view and active:

```
With ActivePresentation
  .Windows(1).Activate
  .Windows(1).View.GotoSlide (1)
  .Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting") ' From 2010 only
  .Application.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus
End With
```